Energy distribution in atomic collision
A photon of energy 10.2 electron Volt collides with a hydrogen atom in ground state. After a certain time interval of few microseconds another photon of energy 15 electron Volt collides inelastically with the same hydrogen atom. Then the observation made by a suitable detector is what ?
The given answer is
A photon with 10.2 electron volt and an electron with 1.4 electron volt .
My doubt =
After the first collision the electron will absorb all the energy and jump to the second orbit from the first . Then during the second collision , since the incoming photon has 15 eV and the electron needs only 3.6ev more to ionize so the electron will gain that energy and ionize. Now we still have 11.6 eV energy left. How do we decide how much energy will be taken by the electron as it's kinetic energy i.e., 1.4ev as stated in the answer and how much energy will be retained by the photon i.e., 10.2 eV as stated in the answer.

The hint is the few microseconds. With that long a time, it ought to be the case that the initial excitation is emitted out again. So the answer is the likely outcome.

If this is the case then shouldn't the ionized hydrogen atom attain some velocity . Why are we considering that all the remaining energy  will be converted into the kinetic energy of the ionized electron ?

True, but the recoil energy is so small that it doesnt really matter there.

Got it !! Thanks
